# Does AWS Lambda load models every time when the function is invoked?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

My requirement is as follows:
**I have multiple models in s3(model1....model100).
I want to use Lambda function for inference using those models**

My inference request will have model number.

Say a request comes to Lambda for inference using model1. Lambda loads the model1 from s3 and does inference. Next request for model2 comes and Lambda does the same with model2.

After 1 hour say another request with model1 comes. Will Lambda again load model1 or will it use the already loaded model1 1 hour back. I have referred the following link [AWS Lambda loading libraries each time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065854/aws-lambda-loading-libraries-each-time)

Please throw some light here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the linked question *not* answer your question? Lambda instances will persist for *some time* (they will be kept "warm"). If another request comes in while the instance is still "warm", it can be handled without reloading the model if your code keeps it in memory. But generally, you should assume that a request will be handled by a *cold* instance and that your code *will* have to reloaded the model.

Comment: There is no better answer than maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/43080302/10320604.
If you can provide more info on what is not clear about this answer maybe we can help.

Comment: You should by default assume every Lambda request is a completely new, independently started instance of your program. Again, if your app is requested frequently, "warm" instances will be reused, which you can use to keep your models in memory and optimise loading. Besides that, there's no way Lambda can "help" you.